# Deep Copy Arraylist Of Objects

Tags: java

for a project I am working on I want to edit an arraylist with my custom Dot objects and pass it into a recursive method, but only the recursive call has the edited arraylist. So I tried to edit it beforehand, pass a copy through, and then change it back, but since it is pass by reference they are each changing the others values. How can I make a deep copy so that I can pass in an edited arraylist, but keep the original intact, as well as keeping them separate? I am setting boolean values that I would like to stay set when using the new method, but aren't actually there in the original arraylist.

```
            for (Dot d : dots) {
                    if (d.isFull() && d.left.isFull() && !(d.left.left.isFull())) {
                        d.setEmpty();
                        d.left.setEmpty();
                        d.left.left.setFull();
                        ArrayList<Dot> newdots = new ArrayList<>(dots);
                        move(newdots);
                        d.setFull();
                        d.left.setFull();
                        d.left.left.setEmpty();
                    }
               
                    if (d.isFull() && d.right.isFull() && !(d.right.right.isFull())) {
                        d.setEmpty();
                        d.right.setEmpty();
                        d.right.right.setFull();
                        ArrayList<Dot> newdots = new ArrayList<>(dots);
                        move(newdots);
                        d.setFull();
                        d.right.setFull();
                        d.right.right.setEmpty();
                    }
```

Comment: Did you try clone object before edit objects?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deep clone a object in Java you have two ways:

1. Use the `clone` method but you have to keep in mind that this method creates a shallow clone. If you have an object which contains references to other objects, only the main object will be cloned. If you want to clone also the children, then you have to override their clone method and in the clone method of the main object you have to invoke them. This should be done recursively for all inner objects.
2. If your main object and all it's children are `Serializable`, then you can use the following method:

   ```
   <T extends Serializable> T deepClone(T t) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
       return deserialize(serialize(t));
   }

   private <T extends Serializable> byte[] serialize(T t) throws IOException {
       try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)) {
           oos.writeObject(t);
           return baos.toByteArray();
       }
   }

   private <T extends Serializable> T deserialize(byte[] data) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
       try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data))) {
           return (T) ois.readObject();
       }
   }
   ```